# Unable to embed a link in Microsoft PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

So I am trying to insert in PowerPoint a link that is capable of opening another PowerPoint, for some reason, it results in an error message. I would appreciate if someone can help me debug this.

By the way, the file definitely exist. [image]

[image]

Edit: operating system MacOS BigSur
office version:16.52

Comment: Operating system? Office version ?

Comment: Please kindly see the update

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but probably you'll need to get the full path of the file, as described for example [in this article](https://setapp.com/how-to/how-to-find-the-path-of-a-file-in-mac)

Comment: You can't hyperlink to just any file. See [Add a hyperlink to a slide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-hyperlink-to-a-slide-239c6c94-d52f-480c-99ae-8b0acf7df6d9).

Comment: Sorry, still deesn't work. I copy paste everything from info option and the result is pretty much the same

Comment: @harrymc "You can't hyperlink to just any file." You can, though if the OS doesn't know what app to open the file in, you'll just get an error message when you click the link.  But that's no relevant in this case; OP's clearly linking to a PPTX.

Comment: @jxhyc If the / is part of the file name, that may be the problem. I don't have a Mac nearby to test with, but try renaming the file; change the / to an underscore or hyphen then create the link again using the full path to the file.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg: The doc says only "Place in This Document", "another presentation" or "E-mail Address". I tried with a simple text file and it didn't work.

Comment: @harrymc What platform are you on? PPT on Windows allows linking to any file and has for the last 20 years at least. On Mac the hyperlink options are "Web page or File", "Place in this document", or "Email address."  You get to this dialog by selecting a shape or text and pressing Command+K.  It's quite possible that your options would be different if you're on the web or iOS versions of PPT, though.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperlinks can't contain spaces, those must be substituted by `%20`. Write the link in the form: `Task%20Achievement/How%20to%20write%20a%20letter.pptx`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your speedy reply. But I am unable to substitute space by %20, it automatically return to the original format.

Comment: Links to other files on the hard drive or local network *can* have spaces in the path or file name.  It may (and probably is) different for links to files on web sites, but that's not what OP is doing in this case (note the lack of a URL-formatted link ... no HTTP://, FTP:// or the like).

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a same environment as yours, but on my Mac environment, the path shown on your image seems to be correct.

The linked "Presentation 2.pptx" as following image shown, could be opened successfully.

[image]

Please try a full file path for a test.

Right-click the file (How to write a Letter) in Finder > Get Info > Copy the path of your file, which starts from "Users". Please also ensuer your current account has **read** and **write permission** to this file.

Then paste the path into Address bar, and add "**file:///**" at the beginning of the path like the following image.

[image]

If a full path does not work, please **move your files to other location** to have a check.